# Where can I get Sai Gita online?

Tags: resource, gita, sai

Where can I find Sai Gita in English online? I am asking about Satya Sai Baba and not about Shirdi Sai Baba.

Comment: This is not a place to ask this question, as here only the Gitas accepted by our tradition are mentioned.You could search the websites of Sri Satya Sai Baba :)

Comment: ...sai gita...?

Comment: @ram I recommend you to read this, this is the only light in kali-yuga.

Comment: @user17439 not all have the Prapthi of reading it. Only those who have pleased HIM immensely can actually believe in HIM and benifit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the complete Sai Gita in English [here](https://archive.org/download/SaiBabaGita/Sai%20Baba%20Gita%20%28244%29.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Geetha vahini pdf is available.That is directly written by Swami and translated in english. [Geetha vahini](http://www.srisathyasai.org.in/Pdf/Geeta_Vahini.pdf)

Comment: Geetha vahini is direct english translation of what BABA wrote with his own hands in telugu. That I feel is more authentic.